# SQL sp_help_operator

Tags: sql, sp-help-operator

Anyone know what group I need to belong to show up in the `sp_help_operator` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the docs for `sp_help_operator`, it looks like you need to explicitly add/remove operators using `sp_add_operator` and `sp_delete_operator`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238703(SQL.80).aspx